# WoT & WoWs launcher error

Tags: world-of-tanks, world-of-warships

i just installed both game, after the installer quit. there's an error

[GAME_NAME] - Critical Error

An unhandled exception is occured.
the application will be restarted.

i close it, when i open both launcher (one at a time of course) the error popped out again.

what should i do ??
how do i fix this ??

i installed it on my windows OS
i istalled it on my hardisk, i got the error.
i installed it on y default directory (c:) still got an error.

Comment: I would change the title. WoW suggests World of Warcraft more then world  of warships.

Comment: WoWs the "s" is the ship.
and the tag is world-of-warships

Comment: anyway, the problem is now fixed, but i dont know what the hell did i just do. so, still you guys give happen again, i can fix it me answer so incase this

Comment: Try doing a clean uninstall and reinstalling it that way. Some file might have been corrupted.